# wordpress installation does not work due to ,htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site running at my server and here is the content of the .htaccees file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|public|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

few days back i installed Wordpress in a folder: example.com/my-blog/ as a stand-alone application
but i could not access it. if i remove the .htaccess file it does work fine but that makes a down the site which in any case i cant not afford. please help.

please help, i am newbie in this.

Comment: That .htaccess file doesn't look right. $1 is going to be blank if it comes right after RewriteEngine on, and so the RewriteRule is never going to be run. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: How to make it correct? can you please help me out in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could exlude your subfolder from rewriting by adding these two lines to your htaccesfile, before your rewriterule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-blog/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!=/my-blog [NC]
```

Ansari is right btw about $1 not being set and therefore, never rewriting anything.

Comment: Thanks looks like it solves it, but if ansari is right, how to correct it then? I am newbie in htaccess and can't understand much here.

Comment: It looks to me you want to exclude the strings starting with those parts from being rewritten.  So I would replace `$1` with `${REQUEST_URI}`.